# Using Bayesian Factors in order to select the most appropriate model

Tags: self-study, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have three models and I use MCMC in order to estimate parameters. In total I have 21, 21 and 42 parameters in three models respectively. Now I am going to select the most appropriate model in between these three models. I use bayesian factor as following. In the first step I estimate parameters in each single model separately and then I recalculate likelihood to find a value. Finally, a model with the minimum likelihood is the most appropriate one.

I see this approach to some extend is different with Bayesian factor(BF). Maybe I am wrong in understanding BF.

Let me explain problem with mathematics. I have a random variable that follows a distribution $F(\mu,\sigma)$. On the other hand in the first model I assume $\mu=a_0 +a_1X_1+....+a_p X_p$ and in the second model I assume $\sigma= b_0+b_1X_1+....+b_pX_p$ where $p$ is the same in both models. In third model I assume both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ comes from a regression model as above.

In total my question is about a method to select the most appropriate model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of Bayes factor is to choose between two models, e.g. between two distribution functions  $F_1$ and $F_2$.

So you basically have $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as your model parameters.

And the data $D$ is 
$$D=\{(x_1,\dots,x_p)_1,\dots,(x_1,\dots,x_p)_n\}$$

The marginal probability if:
$$P_1=\int_{\vec{a}}{\int_{\vec{b}}{\int_D{F_1(\mu(\vec{a}),\sigma(\vec{b}))}}}$$

The Bayes factor is
$$\frac{P_1}{P_2}$$
You can see the interpolation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor)

Comment: thank you so much. So what is $P_2$. On the other hand the integrals are all over the parameter space then how can I calculate that? another question. I am not quite clear about integral over distribution function. Do you mean density function? or maybe likelihood?

Comment: $P_2$ is the same as $P_1$ replacing $F_1$ with $F_2$,  Replace the integral sign with a summation over the posterior distribution you got from the `MCMC`.